# CodeIgniter 3 base_url function returns wrong url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, xampp, base-url

I am using XAMPP, MySQL and CodeIgniter.

I already included,

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

in autoload.php.

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```

returns `http://::1/mysite/` instead of `http://localhost/mysite/`.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have set your base_url in. Most likely because you left it blank. This is a common thing that people do not know about or forget to do.

> application > config > config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mysite/';
```

One of the issues when you try to submit form with out base url not set is will not go to correct url, when you try to submit a form so that why in codeigniter 3 all ways best to set your base_url even though not a requirement.

Also here are some htaccess for codeigniter xampp & wamp

[Htaccess For Codeigniter](https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter)